# Can wardens detect players walking on wool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If **sculk sensors** can't detect me when I walk on **wool**, so do **Wardens** too?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking about unreleased content.

Comment: Hello! To add to what my mod collegue has said: Here at arqade we try to not work on theories and things that cannot be proven 100% that it is as the answer says. And well, with unrelesed content, the best we can do is theorize as to how it will work. So this question will be considered as off-topic for the moment. It could be reopened when the content will be released on at least a public beta channel (I dont know Minecraft much, but basically, when someone not at mojang can freely get and test the update). Have a nice day!

Comment: Voting to reopen, since 1.19 version the Warden was officially released.

Comment: @pinckerman [Unreleased content questions shouldn't be retroactively reopened once the game is released](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6971/185203)

Comment: @pppery didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of Mojang developer, *Kingbdogz*, has confirmed that the Warden has a larger radius for hearing vibrations than the sculk sensor.
He also confirmed in [another tweet](https://twitter.com/kingbdogz/status/1335596684353671168) that the Warden and the skulk sensor **act the exact same** (other than their radius).

[image]

<sub>Source, [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Warden#Trivia).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately as of yet no one knows how the Warden mob is actually going to work in-game.
This is because the Warden does not currently exist on any official update releases or snapshots.